# Automatically scroll on button click in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a tabbed shiny app that generates quite a bit of content based on user inputs and I'm trying to figure out how to scroll to the bottom of the active tab each time new content is generated. I tried implementing the answer given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677726/r-how-do-i-automatically-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-in-shinyapp) but it doesn't seem to work. I'm have minimal experience with javaScript so it may just be something needs to be changed for my specific example. Here is a very silly toy example with my attempt at implementing the answer from the linked question:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(
    '
      Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("scrollCallback",
      function(color) {
      var objDiv = document.getElementById("outDiv");
      objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
      }
      );'
  ),
  tabsetPanel(id = "mainPanels",
    tabPanel("FirstPanel",
      actionButton("outGen", "GenerateOutput"))),
      uiOutput("randomOutput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$randomOutput <- renderUI({
      req(input$outGen)
      lapply(1:50, function(x)p("FooBar"))
    })
    observeEvent(input$outGen,{
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = "scrollCallback", 1)
    })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui,server))
```

I'm trying to find a way to scroll to the bottom of the tab once the generate output button is pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fixup that works. The following changes were made:

- Changed the initialization so that there is some text rendered to that `div` before we start. This is necessary otherwise some of the variables will not be initialized properly in the `div` object.
- Modified the text output so it changes every time (for better testing)
- Added the necessary CSS overflow:auto style to the `randomOutput` div so that you would have a scroll bar to scroll.
- Fixed up some minor typos (`getElementById` was querying the wrong div)
- added some debugging output to `scrollCallback`

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style('#randomOutput {   height: 450px;   overflow: auto;}'),
  tags$script(
    '
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("scrollCallback",
    function(msg) {
    console.log("aCMH" + msg)
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("randomOutput");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight - objDiv.clientHeight;
    console.dir(objDiv)
    console.log("sT:"+objDiv.scrollTop+" = sH:"+objDiv.scrollHeight+" cH:"+objDiv.clientHeight)
    }
    );'
  ),
  tabsetPanel(id = "mainPanels",
              tabPanel("FirstPanel",
                       actionButton("outGen", "GenerateOutput"))),
  uiOutput("randomOutput")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  n <- 0
  output$randomOutput <- renderUI({
    input$outGen
    n <<- n + 50
    lapply(1:50, function(x)p(paste0("FooBar-",x+n-50)))
  })
  observeEvent(input$outGen,{
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "scrollCallback", 1)
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui,server))
```

and here is what it looks like on testing:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the very complete answer.

Comment: This might be beyond the scope of the original question but is there a way to do this by accessing the main body scroll? This would be applicable when instead of using one uiOutput a shiny app used multiple uiOutupts. So you couldn't scroll within the div of each individual output.

Comment: Never mind I just figured it out by putting `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);` into the function instead of the lines that access the div.