# R shiny app, making a log that scrolls down automatically

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I am trying to make a log in shiny, which text is taken from a reactive value updated by a function. The log is in a `verbatimTextOutput` and I want it to be scrolled down each time it is updated. For this purpose I use a function using a javascript code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392748/automatically-scroll-on-button-click-in-shiny), but it does not work when used immediately after the console update, it in fact scrolls down to the level of the previous update (because the UI values are not yet updated?). I tried different methods to launch the function at different times and could not get the scrollbar to the bottom.

Here is an example of what I am trying, I would like the "Add Text" button to scroll all the way down, but only the "Force scroll update" button does it:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.scrollDown = function() {
                            var objDiv = document.getElementById('log');
                            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight - objDiv.clientHeight;
                          }"),
  tags$style(HTML("#log {height:80px}")), br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("log", placeholder = TRUE),
  actionButton("add", "Add Text"),
  actionButton("force", "Force scroll update")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  a <- reactiveValues(
    logOutput = "TEST"
  )

  output$log <- renderText({ a$logOutput })

  updateLog <- function(text){
    a$logOutput <- paste(a$logOutput, text, sep = "\n")
  }

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    updateLog("TEST")
    js$scrollDown()
  })  

  observeEvent(input$force,{
    js$scrollDown()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope this can be done, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option:

```
js <- "
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(evt){
  if(evt.name == 'log'){
    setTimeout(function(){
      var objDiv = document.getElementById('log');
      objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight - objDiv.clientHeight;
    }, 500); // wait 500 milliseconds
  }
});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  tags$style(HTML("#log {height:80px}")), br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("log", placeholder = TRUE),
  actionButton("add", "Add Text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  a <- reactiveValues(
    logOutput = "TEST"
  )

  output$log <- renderText({ a$logOutput })

  updateLog <- function(text){
    a$logOutput <- paste(a$logOutput, text, sep = "\n")
  }

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    updateLog("TEST")
  })  

}
```

---

A solution without delaying, using `MutationObserver`:

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  var objDiv = document.getElementById('log');
  // create an observer instance
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight - objDiv.clientHeight;
  });
  // configuration of the observer
  var config = {childList: true};
  // observe objDiv
  observer.observe(objDiv, config);
})
"
```

Comment: Thank you this solution works for me, I just changed the delay to 1 ms and it's perfect for my purpose!

Comment: @Ganthark Nice. See my edit. I've added a solution that does not use `setTimeout`.